# `_id` in where clause

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I face an issue trying to access `_id` in a query.where.

My schema:

```
var testSchema  = new Schema({
    test2id: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Test2' }],
    test3id: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Test3' }]
});

var test2Schema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var test3Schema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
```

My query:

```
testSchema.statics.findByid = function (id, callback) {
  var query = this.findOne();

  Test2.findOne({'name': name}, function (error, t2) {
    query.where({
        test2id: _id,
    }).exec(callback);
  });
  return query
};
```

`_id` is undefined, I try also `this._id` but the query return null.
I just want to get all documents from `testSchema` with `test2id = _id` of the `testSchema` document.

Any idea to fix that and access to `_id` from a `query.where` clause?

Comment: Post your `TestSchema` `Test2` schema and a document example from both these collections.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera: I edited my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve it by passing it in parameter.

```
var test = new Test();
test.findByid(test._id, req.params.id, function(err, res) {
    ...
});
```